# Where are valid password reset tokens stored?

Tags: users

When one submits the form on `user/password` or executes `drush uli`, a password token is generated. Where does Drupal store these?

Comment: I do not think Drupal stores password tokens. I have used drush uli many times and it generates a one time login link, similar to link generated by user_pass_reset_url(). You should see the functions coding http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_pass_reset_url/7

Comment: I see, you're right. When someone tries to use a hash the hash is recreated and compared to the supplied one. If you want to post an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: :) glad this helped you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think Drupal stores password tokens. I have used `drush uli` many times and it generates a one time login link, similar to link generated by [user_pass_reset_url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_pass_reset_url/7). You should see the functions coding